# How to count number of features detected by ORB?

Tags: python, opencv, feature-extraction, feature-detection, orb

How do I count the number of features detected through ORB? The openCV python code I used for ORB is:

```
import cv2 as cv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img = cv.imread('maple.jpg', 0)
orb = cv.ORB_create()
kp = orb.detect(img, None)
kp, des = orb.compute(img, kp)
img2 = cv.drawKeypoints(img, kp, None, color=(0, 255, 0), flags=0)
plt.imshow(img2), plt.show()
```

This is the result:
[image: Result]

Comment: kp should be a list of those keypoints. I dont know enough about python, but it probable has some kind of `size` or `len` function for that datatype

Comment: try count=len(kp)